# Hide header and footer in custom pdf Prestashop

Tags: pdf-generation, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I made method to print custom pdf in my module in Prestashop 1.7.4.1. Everything works fine, but it print header with shop logo and footer with information about electronic invoice on every page. How can I hide them that my template take all size of the printed page?

I've tried to add to my pdf object code from tcpdf example but it seems I don't use TCPDF in presta:

```
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
```

This is my class:

```
class HTMLTemplateCustomPdf extends HTMLTemplate
{
    public $custom_model;

    public function __construct($custom_object, $smarty)
    {
        $this->custom_model = $custom_object;
        $this->smarty = $smarty;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the template's HTML content
     * @return string HTML content
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        //here I get content

        return $this->smarty->fetch(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'ps_first_module/views/templates/hook/pdf.tpl');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the template filename
     * @return string filename
     */
    public function getFilename()
    {
        return 'custom_pdf.pdf';
    }

    /**
     * Returns the template filename when using bulk rendering
     * @return string filename
     */
    public function getBulkFilename()
    {
        return 'custom_pdf.pdf';
    }
```

This is where I create pdf object:

```
if (Tools::isSubmit('print')) {
    if (Shop::getContext() != Shop::CONTEXT_GROUP && Shop::getContext() != Shop::CONTEXT_ALL) {
        require_once _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'ps_first_module/HTMLTemplateCustomPdf.php';
        $orientation = 'L';
        $pdf = new PDF($custom_object, 'CustomPdf', Context::getContext()->smarty, $orientation);
        $pdf->render();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
This is my PDFGenerator.php override. Should I put this in root/override/classes/pdf or my_module/override/classes/pdf?

```
<?php
class PDFGenerator extends PDFGeneratorCore
{
    /**
     * @param bool $use_cache
     * @param string $orientation
     */
    public function __construct($use_cache = false, $orientation = 'L')
    {
        parent::__construct($orientation, 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', $use_cache, false);
        $this->setRTL(Context::getContext()->language->is_rtl);
    }

    /**
     * Write a PDF page
     */
    public function writePage()
    {
        if(!$this->header){
       $this->SetHeaderMargin(0);
       }
       else{
           $this->SetHeaderMargin(5);
       }

       if(!$this->footer){
           $this->SetFooterMargin(0);
       }
       else{
           $this->SetFooterMargin(21);
       }

       $this->setMargins(10, 10, 10);
       $this->AddPage();
       $this->writeHTML($this->content, true, false, true, false, '');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried in version 1.7.2 and file properties mention Producer: TCPDF 6.2.12 (http://www.tcpdf.org). Also, class Pdf in function render() as:

```
$this->pdf_renderer->createHeader($template->getHeader());
$this->pdf_renderer->createFooter($template->getFooter());
```

So, the best way would be your class HTMLTemplateCustomPdf to include the functions getHeader() and getFooter() to return false (or empty) otherwise it will use those from HTMLTemplateCore.

In the override for PDFGenerator, you can do something like:

```
public function writePage()
{
    if(!$this->header){
        $this->SetHeaderMargin(0);
    }
    else{
        $this->SetHeaderMargin(5);
    }

    if(!$this->footer){
        $this->SetFooterMargin(0);
    }
    else{
        $this->SetFooterMargin(21);
    }

    $this->setMargins(10, 40, 10);
    $this->AddPage();
    $this->writeHTML($this->content, true, false, true, false, '');
}
```

You can also set different margins if needed in $this->setMargins(10, 40, 10);

Comment: Ok it works, but now I have a huge margin on top of document. I accept the answer, but maybe you know how to remove this margin now.

Comment: I was wondering if there would be a margin. I think you need to override the pdfgenerator writePage() to set different margins.

Comment: Ok I found how to override class, but I don't understand overrides. Can you explain to me how use it in my custom pdf? What I have to do after override this class?

Comment: @pelkas13 i've added the override example. let me know if it worked as you needed.

Comment: Could you check my edit? I tried to put this file into my_module/override/classes/pdf but then it seems like my module doesn't work well. Also the print orientation isn't landscape like I want.

Comment: @pelkas13 To test the file, you can put the file in the main override folder /override/classes/pdf. You should also clear the cache, by deleting the folders: /app/cache/dev and/or /app/cache/prod. The same folder inside your module is only used to copy the override to the main override folder on install. And change to parent::__construct($use_cache, $orientation); in the override